# Django ManyToMany Field in Both Tables

Tags: mysql, django

The Django docs say you can put a many to many field in either side's model, but not both. Example showing Pizzas and Toppings says it's more "normal" to think of the toppings on a pizza than think of which pizzas a topping is on, so put the field in the pizza model.  OK...

However, in my application which tracks permissions and groups, this is not necessarily true. The application has a many-to-many in the permissions table showing which groups have that permission. It also seems like you should be able to look at a group and see what permissions it has. This would theoretically use the same join table.

Couldn't I add a many-to-many-through field in the groups model and specify the existing permission_group join table? Would this cause problems, as it directly violates the recommendation in the ManyToMany documentation?

Thanks...

Comment: I'm confused, if seeing which permissions each group has is what you need, why not just use Goups.permission_set.all()  ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Patrick. Please see my answer to Makaveli below. Also, I'm new enough at Django that I wouldn't know where/how to use the suggestion you gave.  I'll keep looking...

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see the reason for it. It doesn't matter which end of an electrified wire you touch - the end result is the same. What happens on the database level is exactly the same with no regard to where you add the field in Django. You can still do reverse lookups from either side (check out documentation about `related_name` setting, it's handy) so you can get both
a) all persons with some specific permissions
b) all permissions that a user has

If you try what you propose, you will end up with two parallel M2M fields if Django allows that - and I imagine it does, but that doesn't make any sense at all. It's like talking to the same person over two phones at the same time - why would you do that? Don't.
And as Patrick mentioned, Django has a comprehensive permissions system so you might just want to check that out and maybe it will suit your needs without any effort on your part at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have to think about what you folks said. I don't understand your comparison. If you bring up a particular permission for edit, it seems reasonable to see/change what groups have that permission.  Ditto if you bring up a particular group for edit. It seems reasonable to add or subtract to/from the same join table from either end.  Sometimes you are working on the group, sometimes you are working on the permission. I really want to understand this so I can get it right.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a distinction where there is none. The point of a many-to-many is that it *is* automatically accessible from either side of the relationship; Django does that for you. The point the docs were making was that the difference is a semantic one only; in the case they mention, toppings belong to pizzas. But even doing it that way, you can still access the pizzas from each topping.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. What I'd *like* to do is put a ManyToManyThrough field in the toppings side so I could add or remove relationships from either end. I know you can access from either end as Patrick mentioned above, but I'd like a MTM field on each form that could interact with the join table. Obviously I'd have to use "through" and mention the already-existing join table, right?

Comment: I'm new at Django too. So I have no answer. But I want to say that your question is easy to undestand and completly legal. The things are not symetrical in Dajngo, but they should be symetrical in the real world.